# Python code acts differently in file and Terminal

Tags: python

guys, I'm learning Python recently, I got a problem when I write some simple codes in Python Shell(command in Terminal in Linux) and in a file:

in Python Shell:

```
>>> def firstn(n):
...     num, nums = 0, []
...     while num < n:
...         nums.append(nums)
...         num += 1
...     return nums
... sum_of_first_n = sum(firstn(1000000))
  File "<stdin>", Line7
    sum_of_firstn_n = sum(firstn(1000000))
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

if print(sum(firstn(1000000))), the print will be a SyntaxError too

But when I put the codes into a file, and execute it, it is totally OK, no SyntaxError, I don't know why. Is there anyone who can explain this?
PS: The code is from https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In interactive mode, put blank line to end the block.

```
>>> def firstn(n):
...     num, nums = 0, []
...     while num < n:
...         nums.append(nums)
...         num += 1
...     return nums
...
>>> sum_of_first_n = sum(firstn(1000000))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

BTW, the code make a cyclic reference in the following line:

```
nums.append(nums)
```

---

```
>>> def firstn(n):
...     num, nums = 0, []
...     while num < n:
...         nums.append(num) # <--
...         num += 1
...     return nums
...
>>> sum_of_first_n = sum(firstn(1000000))
>>> sum_of_first_n
499999500000L
```

Comment: Thanks, the first line "In interactive mode, put blank line to end the block." is very useful to me, I should define every block in different part in the shell.But the rest of your answer makes confused, I didn't get the TypeError like your(BTW, I'm using Python 3.2),

Comment: @codychan, See this line: `nums.append(nums)`. This add `nums` to `nums` itself!

Comment: @codychan I would recommend *always* adding a blank line after a function definition.  It says somewhere in [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) that you should do that, and anyway it will make it easier for your to copy and paste into your interactive python sessions.

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine for me when I copied directly from the Python docs. When I tried adding a space before the last line (sum_of_first_n) I received that same syntax error message. Most likely a copy paste error. Try copying to a text editor to check for spaces and then paste into terminal.

Comment: Thanks anyway, the space is not the problem, the lack of a blank line is, just like @falsetru answered. BTW, I didn't copy and paste the codes into my terminal, I typed them by hands, so there's no "a space before last line" issue.